# map dates in ship week sql

Tags: sql, date

I'm trying to map ship_date to the correct ship_wk (our ship weeks go from Sunday to Saturday) and I'm not sure how to do it.

The table the ship week field pulls from is currently mapping them incorrectly. For example, ship_wk = 42 should show dates 10/14 - 10/20, but is showing 10/21 - 10/27.

I need to create a different ship week field within my query that uses the correct mapping. I've never worked with dates in this capacity. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, an explanation of what "mapping them incorrectly" means, and an appropriate dtabase tag.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [ask], edit your question, and include table definitions, example data.  Thanks